# Shared Authentication between Web and class library projects

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity

I have a Solution divided into 3 projects.
Two of them are MVC 5 web apps which use ASP.Net Identity provider.
One is a class library which is referenced by the other projects. All the CRUD actions take place in here.

All the projects point to same DB and operate via EF.

All the business logic happens in the class library but is user agnostic. User validation happens in web apps only. Problems here are user validation code is repeated across all web projects and the class library has no idea of the user invoking an API.
This kind of architecture will bring maintenance nightmares very soon so I would like only the class library to talk to db for business logic or user validation.
Now, since ASP.Net Identity provider doesn't work in class libraries, anybody found a way around it?

Comment: What gave you you the impression that the Simple Membership provider doesn't work in class library projects?

Comment: Sorry Ben. Its Asp.Net Identity provider in my project. Not Simple Membership provider. Updated my question accordingly.

Comment: In which case, same question for ASP.NET Identity. There is no reason why this can't be added to a class library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what "maintenance nightmare" you are referring to by having security in the web application.  It is a good thing to decouple your application domain from your security model. Your domain model and business logic may remain the same across certain web applications but the security model may vary.  I would not bundle these together. And if it is in your class libraries how will you let the OWIN security framework handle forms authentication for you. Are you going to manage all of this in your class libraries as well.

When you refer to "user validation" I assume you are talking about authorization.  If you must perform authorization in your class libraries I would implement a custom [ClaimsAuthorizationManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.claims.claimsauthorizationmanager%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). You would override the [CheckAccess](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.claims.claimsauthorizationmanager.checkaccess%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method to perform your authorization.  The ClaimsAuthorizationManager is configured in your web.config so you could have different ClaimsAuthorizationManager's for different web applications. But the logic in your class libraries would remain the same. Anywhere that you want to authorize the user before performing an action you would insert:

```
ClaimsPrincipalPermission.CheckAccess("MyResource", "MyAction");
```

The resource and action passed is used in the custom ClaimsAuthorizationManager you created to know the context in which the authorization is taking place. I talk about this method for [decoupling your security model from your application domain in this article](http://kevin-junghans.blogspot.com/2013/09/decoupling-your-security-model-revisited.html). If the authorization fails a SecurityException is thrown. You would let this percolate up to your web application where you handle it appropriately (redirect in a controller or an HTTP unauthorized error for Web APi's).  Note that this architecture will work if you use your class libraries in non-web applications as well. I have used this with ASP.NET Identity and it works well.